# How to write functional test case in asp.net core using XUnit tool?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, functional-testing

I have to write a functional test case for my asp.net core project.

I don't have any idea about functional test case writing.

Could you please help me to write functional test case using X unit?

Comment: https://xunit.github.io/

Comment: Hi Sergey, Thanks for your reply. However, i have written unit test cases for my project using XUnit. So I know how to use XUnit. The problem is that I don't know how to write functional test case using X unit.

Comment: Suppose we have a login page and after login, we get a list of data. For this scenario, i have to write functional test. I am confused, what would be there in the functional test method.

Comment: Do i need to call every management class method which are in the flow of source to destination?

Comment: shouldn't we call controller actiopn method for the functional test?

Comment: For functional testing I would use something like Selenium (for opening pages, manipulating them and getting data). XUnit should be used to verify what you got by Selenium

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for writing the functional test cases using XUnit. First, you have to find out methods throughout the flow of functions. Call each and every method from the functional test method. We do not need to mock anything. Every call throughout the flow will be real from end to end.Assert all success call which we got from methods. Everything will be real for functional test. Do not need to execute every line of code. Just call methods which are responsible for data fetch and data save.

Comment: How to bootstrap the application and the service container to kick in?